# Copy a row of data to the textfields of same page on selecting a row through radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

Dynamically generating rows by jquery

```
$("#showbtn").on("click", function() {
                var tblRow;
                $.getJSON('multimob.action', $("#mobileno").serialize(), function(data) {
                    if (data.mobileno === null) {
                        alert("Wrong Mobile No.,please Check");
                    } else {
                        $.each(data.ls, function(index, value) {
                            var count = index;
                            tblRow = $("<tr><td> <input type='radio' id='chk' name='chk' onclick='copyrecord('" + count + "');'/></td><td id='fidrow" + count + "'>" + value.id + "</td>"
                                    + "<td>" + value.name + "</td>" + "<td>"
                                    + value.mobileno + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.addres + "</td></tr>");
                            alert(count + tblRow.toString());
                            $("#farmTable tbody").append(tblRow);
                        });
                    });
```

The data rows are dynamically created ,Once I select the radio button, it should take the data from that row and it has to be copied to the textfields in the same page .

Help me to get rid of this iisue.

Comment: You want to copy the entire data or something specific like phone number..?

Comment: `id='chk'` it gets repeated so that will cause in an invalid markup.

Comment: @T J : I want to copy the selected row data,i.e id,name,mobile no and address to the textfields in the same page.

Comment: @Jai id='chk' is an attribute value of radio button field. name and id attribute holds same value. 'chk' has not been given to any other input types

Comment: @Mathu so there is just one row in your table.

Comment: @Jai Oh no !It dynamically gets the data, One or more rows! so I can change the id and name as 'chk"+count+"' something like this. But how can I copy the row data on selecting the row by radio button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example

Use class

```
<input type='radio' id='chk' name='chk' class="chk"/>
```

HTML

```
$(document).on('click','.chk',function(){
var text=[];
$(this).parents('tr').find('td:not(:first)').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).text()) 
   text.push($(this).text())     
});
$('#name').val(text[0]);
$('#no').val(text[1]);
$('#add').val(text[2])
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TTcjT/2/)

Comment: Does it work for dynamically generated rows with radio button @Sridhar R

Comment: @Mathu Yes it will work with class thats why i use `$(document).on('click'`

Comment: @Mathu just insert after document.ready, your checkbox must generated with class=chk

Comment: Yep,It's working, Can I cut the values as per each column, since I wanna paste it in three different textfields.  I tried by using "index", but didn't work

Comment: Thank You So much! I was trying the same,your updated answer worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment: *I can change the id and name as 'chk"+count+"' something like this. But how can I copy the row data on selecting the row by radio button*

You can get it this way:

```
$("#farmTable").on('change', '[id^="chk"]', function(){
    var tblVals = $("#farmTable tr").map(function(){
       return $(this).find('td:not(:first)').text();
    });
    console.log(tblVals);
});
```